# fixed position of inner div related to its container

Tags: html, css

if have the following code:

```
<div id="container" style="position:relative; width:300px; height:300px; overflow:scroll;">
    <div id="header">
    </div>
    <div>
    a table of contents
    </div>
</div>
```

how do i make the inner div with the id "header" follows when i scroll down the outer div "container"?
TIA
Lina

Comment: Did you try style="position:fixed" on the header?

Comment: yes, but then it follows when i scroll the page and not only when i scroll the "container"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to exactly what i want to do here:
http://www.cubido.at/Default.aspx?tabid=176&EntryID=8
although i thought the answer is going to be simpler, but seems that css alone won't fix it, although it would be very helpful to have something like "position: fixed;" that works not only relative to page but to containing element...

Answer (score 1):

Put the header outside of the container. It's useless to let it in since you don't want to display it inside.

Comment: i have to display it inside, as i have something like this:
<form>
radio button 1, radio button 2, radio button 3
</form>
<div id="container">
    <div id="header">
    <table>calendar</table>
    </div>
    
    <div>
    <table> a lot of rows </table>
    </div>
</div>

when radio button 1 is chosen then calendar is all days in a year,
radio button 2, calendar is only months of the year,
radio button 3, calendar is only year

and the contents depend also on that, so i have to include it inside the big container