# CSS. Fixed position related to div

Tags: html, css

I found how to fix div position using jQuery.

Here is an [example](http://www.wduffy.co.uk/blog/keep-element-in-view-while-scrolling-using-jquery/).

Can I achieve same effect using css?

**UPD**: I have seen this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2522114/fixed-position-of-inner-div-related-to-its-container). I want also horizontal window scrollbar to appear, if fixed element does not fit the window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the same effect without the cool whizz-bangs and animations with `position: fixed`. The fixed element will then just scroll along.

As for horizontal scrollbar when content doesn't fit the window, just define `width: 100%` and `overflow-x: scroll` for the fixed element .

Comment: `overflow-x: scroll` affects only element. I need standart browser horizontal scroll to appear for **window**. It's appears if element has `position:absolute`, and not appears if element has `position:fixed`.